# DropDownList View Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to produce a dropdownlist for GetAllRoles using the role provider.

I can produce the drop down in a controller using ViewData but I would like to use a View Model to produce the dropdown, but I'm unsure of the best way to create the list using a View Model?

```
public ActionResult GetAllRoles()
{
   ViewData["Roles"] = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles());
   return View(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Depending on how you want to do it,</strike>

```
var allroles = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles()); 
return View(allRoles);
```

Create a strongly typed view of type SelectList.

Based on your recent comment.

```
public SelectList GetAllRoles() { 
  var AllRoles = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles()); 
  return AllRoles; 
} 

public class RoleViewModel {
  [Required]
  [DisplayName("AllRoles")]
  public SelectList AllRoles { get; set; }
}


public ActionResult GetAllRoles() 
{ 
   var roleViewModel = new RoleViewModel {
      AllRoles = GetAllRoles();
   };
   return View(roleViewModel);  
}
```

Comment: I would like to add the GetAllRoles in my model not in the controller.

public string GetAllRoles()
{
 var AllRoles = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles());
 return AllRoles;
}

[Required]
[DisplayName("AllRoles")]
public String AllRoles { get; set; }

Comment: Thanks Raj that's working great, I think I was just using a string rather than a SelectList. When I'm now creating my strongly typed View it doesn't seem to create the HTML.Dropdown code. Would I just add this myself? I would have liked to the use Html.EditorFor().

Comment: Would I just add this myself? Unfortunately, yes.